# How to design a ordered list inside a selection drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to try something like this inside my webpage, so below needs to look exactly inside a drop down list or  statement.

```
  (a). Category1
          element1
          element2
          etc..

  (b).Category2
          element1
          element2
          etc..
```

This is how I tried, but it shows me in a normal drop down list menu instead to look like the above one.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <select>
    <ol>
     <option value=1><li>Category1</li></option>
     <option value =2><li>element1</li></option>
     <option value =3><li>element2</li></option>
     <option value =4><li>etc...</li></option>
     <option value =5><li>Category2</li></option>
     <option value =6><li>element1</li></option>
     <option value =7><li>element2</li></option>
     <option value =8><li>etc...</li></option>
    </ol>
   </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion or idea, how can I do this using HTML CSS or any scripts? can we create a exact look inside the drop down  menu? any help on this would be great!

Thanks

Comment: look into using [<optgroup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) any other tag element besides that and `<option>` are invalid inside `<select>` tags

Comment: Thank you Patrick Evans, can you please guide more, why is `<option>` tag is invalid inside `<select>` tag

Comment: i didnt say option was invalid i said any other tag besides optgroup and option are invalid.

Comment: oh my bad, sorry about that! got the point, Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `optgroup` tag may be what your after?

Something like:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Category 1">
        <option value="2">element1</option>
        <option value="3">element2</option>
        <option value="4">etc...</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Category 2">
        <option value="5">element1</option>
        <option value="6">element2</option>
        <option value="7">etc...</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z5KrN/

Comment: Thank you carl, I have never used this tag before so have no clue. I will search more!